# Creating grouped boxplots with Plotly

Tags: r

I have a data set with 24 patients, 2 conditions, 19 variables and would like to create a grouped boxplot in plotly displaying individual data points, connecting the paired data and display the statistics.

Here is my code illustrating the attempt to plot one variable:

```
#Bind it
DF<- rbind(First.numeric, Combined.numeric)
#Subset it
both<- grep("^to_water.conc.glu", names(DF), value=TRUE)
onetomerge<- melt(DF,id.var=c ("nr_patient"), measure.vars=both)
#Sort it 
onetomerge<-onetomerge %>% dplyr::arrange(nr_patient)
#Name it
name<- c("first", "merged")
name<-rep(name, times = 24) #456
dat <- data.frame(cond = (name), value = onetomerge)
#plot it
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=value.variable, y=value.value, fill=cond)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_point() +
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", paired = TRUE) 
ggplotly(p)
```

This is the result it yields:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6cZN.png)

When I try running the ggplot portion without plotly, my boxplots are separate but the points overlapped in the center, whereas when I run it with plotly my individual points are separated by colour yet the boxplots are overlapped in the center. I have also gone through the plotly documentation, without any luck. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `ggplotly(p) %>% layout(boxmode='group')`. You'll get a warning "'layout' objects don't have these attributes: 'boxmode'" but you should be able to ignore it and the plot should be what you're expecting. From the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461337/plotly-ggplot-multiple-boxplot-groups) there may be some differences in the boxplots between `plotly` and `ggplot` as a heads up.

Comment: Thanks! @TrainingPizza that solved the boxplots from being overlapped :D